# Controller to Ajax Estimate Shipping - Load Block and display phtml

Tags: shipping, blocks, layout, controllers, ajax

I copied estimatePostAction and made `estimateAjaxPostAction` (overrided core - i did not hack the core). The controller action works as well (class `Mage_Checkout_CartController`).

Now I want to get/create a block for replace shipping block after estimate shipping with ajax. I tried this:

```
public function estimateAjaxPostAction()
{
    $country    = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('country_id');
    $postcode   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_postcode');
    $city       = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_city');
    $regionId   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region_id');
    $region     = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');

    $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
    ->setCountryId($country)
    ->setCity($city)
    ->setPostcode($postcode)
    ->setRegionId($regionId)
    ->setRegion($region)
    ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $this->_getQuote()->save();
    //$this->_goBack();

    $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping','checkout.cart.shipping.ajax',array('template' => 'checkout/cart/shipping.phtml'));
    if($block) {
        $response = array();
        $response['shipping'] = $block->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
    }
}
```

The block checkout.cart.shipping.ajax was created. But toHtml() returns nothing.
My json returns: `{"shipping":""}`

Why toHtml method doesn't work?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Answered at StackOverflow by Amit Bera: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601634/magento-controller-to-ajax-estimate-shipping-load-block-and-display-phtml

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
....

$loadLayout = $this->loadLayout();

$block = $loadLayout->createBlock(
         'checkout/cart_shipping',
         'checkout.cart.shipping.ajax'
)->setTemplate('checkout/cart/shipping.phtml');

if($block) {
    $response = array();
    $response['shipping'] = $block->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
}

....
```

Comment: oh, you wrote description for your name, awesome boss.....